# range and input type validation

Tags: java, validation, input, while-loop

I have a problem. The code is supposed to take in 2 digit integers where the digits are different. If it's not an integer the code tells you and asks to reenter. If it as integer but doesn't meet conditions it will tell you and then prompt to reenter. Everything works except when you enter 0 for ending the loop/program. I've been stuck on this for 2 days. Any suggestions?

```
    int num = 1;
    while (num != 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop: ");
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Not an integer, try again: ");
            in.next();
        }
        num = in.nextInt();
        while (num < 10 || num > 99) {
            System.out.println("NOT good for your game!");
            System.out.print("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop: ");
            while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("Not an integer, try again: ");
                in.next();
            }
            num = in.nextInt();
        }
        if (equalDigs(num) == false)
            System.out.println("NOT good for you game!");
        else
            System.out.println("Good for your game! Play!");

    }

}
public static boolean equalDigs(int n) {
    int d1 = n / 10;
    int d2 = n % 10;

    if (d1 == d2)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You should use a do-while for this use case. Try, it will highly simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the duplicated checks. You can use a `do-while` statement instead of a `while` statement in order to reduce the number of checks :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int num;
  do {
    System.out.print("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop: ");
    String input = in.next();
    try {
      num = Integer.valueOf(input);
      if(num == 0) {
        break;
      }
      if(num < 10 || num > 99) {
        System.out.println("NOT good for your game!");
      } else{
        if(input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(1)) {
          System.out.println("NOT good for you game!");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Good for your game! Play!");
        }
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
      System.out.print("Not an integer, try again: ");
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it but is there a way to it without the exceptions? This is an intro class and we haven't gone over all that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to refactor your code would be to read in a `String` from the command line instead of reading a number, and then validating that input to make sure it meets the following conditions:

- input length is two characters
- both characters are numbers
- the first and second numbers are unique

I created a method called `validate()` which does the heavy lifting for this.  This leaves your `main()` method focusing only on polling the user for input so long as validation fails.

```
public static boolean validate(String input) {
    // check that input length is two characters
    if (input.length() != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    // check that a two digit number was entered
    if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0)) < 0 || Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0)) > 9 ||
        Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0)) < 0 || Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0)) > 9) {
        return false;
    }
    // check that first and second numbers are unique
    if (input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(1)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop: ");
        input = reader.next();
        if (!validate(input)) {
            System.out.println("NOT good for your game!");
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while(true);

    System.out.println("Good for your game! Play!");
    // you can also use the value of 'input' here if needed
}
```

Comment: Appreciate but can it be done without String and .getNumericalValue because we haven't learned .getNu... and you're supposed to be entering int's not Strings

Comment: The advantage of mg solution is that the user can enter anything he wants.  If the input is non numeric the code will simply reject it and ask again.